# Mahapps.Metro: Custom Icon Textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I would like to add a icon to the mahapps.metro textbox, much like the clear button for the textbox. The mahapps.metro demo app has this feature, and even after looking at the source code don't understand how to implement it. From `TextExamples.xaml` in the Metro Demo app the code bellow code creates a custom icon and binds it to a event. However, I can't implement it myslef in my own code. I can't tell at all where it is getting the custom icon from. Thanks from

```
<TextBox Margin="0, 10, 0, 0"
                         Controls:TextboxHelper.Watermark="Custom icon style"
                         Controls:TextboxHelper.ButtonContent="s"
                         Controls:TextboxHelper.ButtonCommand="{Binding TextBoxButtonCmd,  Mode=OneWay}"
                         Style="{DynamicResource MetroButtonTextBox}" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is the example how the search `TextBox` works (and should work with your custom vector icon or something else too)

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}"
       x:Key="SearchMetroTextBox"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroButtonTextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Controls:TextboxHelper.ButtonTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Grid x:Name="contentPresenter"
                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                          SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                          Opacity="0.75">
                        <Canvas Width="15"
                                Height="15"
                                Clip="F1 M 0,0L 48,0L 48,48L 0,48L 0,0">
                            <!-- x:Key="appbar_magnify"-->
                            <Path Width="15.7781"
                                  Height="15.7781"
                                  Stretch="Fill"
                                  Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                  Data="F1 M 14.8076,31.1139L 20.0677,25.9957C 19.3886,24.8199 19.25,23.4554 19.25,22C 19.25,17.5817 22.5817,14 27,14C 31.4183,14 35,17.5817 35,22C 35,26.4183 31.4183,29.75 27,29.75C 25.6193,29.75 24.3204,29.6502 23.1868,29.0345L 17.8861,34.1924C 17.105,34.9734 15.5887,34.9734 14.8076,34.1924C 14.0266,33.4113 14.0266,31.895 14.8076,31.1139 Z M 27,17C 24.2386,17 22,19.2386 22,22C 22,24.7614 24.2386,27 27,27C 29.7614,27 32,24.7614 32,22C 32,19.2386 29.7614,17 27,17 Z " />
                        </Canvas>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                             Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="contentPresenter"
                                Property="Opacity"
                                Value="1" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                             Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="contentPresenter"
                                Property="Opacity"
                                Value=".5" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                             Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                Value="#ADADAD" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

hope that helps

Comment: I know this is old post, but how do I attached a click event in the textbox button/icon?

Thanks

Comment: @klaydze just bind your own command to `Controls:TextboxHelper.ButtonCommand`

Answer (score 3):

The documentation in the source code does not mention it, but it appears the `Controls:TextboxHelper.ButtonContent` Property is what controls the custom icons.  You have to set the `ButtonContent` Property to the font character you want in this font called Marlett Characters

http://www.reactos.org/wiki/Marlett_Characters

I found this answer in the project's GitHub site
https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/issues/849

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer, just direction where to check for implementation of Icon in TextBox by MahApps.Metro.

First thing I will do is to check [Controls.TextBox.xaml](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/master/MahApps.Metro/Styles/Controls.TextBox.xaml) file. There is where `MetroButtonTextBox` style implemented :

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroTextBox}"
       x:Key="MetroButtonTextBox">
    <Setter Property="Controls:TextboxHelper.ButtonTemplate"
            Value="{DynamicResource ChromelessButtonTemplate}" />
    <!-- change SnapsToDevicePixels to True to view a better border and validation error -->
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            ......
            ......
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And I guess (haven't dug too deep on this), the Icon is *button* part of the TextBox. Therefore you may need to go through `ChromelessButtonTemplate` too. `ChromelessButtonTemplate` resource declaration can be found in [Controls.Buttons.xaml](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/master/MahApps.Metro/Styles/Controls.Buttons.xaml) file.

And about those 3 attached behaviors/properties (`Watermark`, `ButtonContent`, and `ButtonCommand`), definition can be found in [TextboxHelper.cs](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/master/MahApps.Metro/Controls/TextboxHelper.cs) file.